# How to cite author[numeric_ref] in citation

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I am a beginner in LaTeX and do not know much about modification of the usual package. I am providing the minimum working code that I tried and then describe my problem.

I have the `lauraPhd2016.bib` with following data

```
    @article{wombat2016,
    author   = {Walther Wombat and Klaus Koala},
    title    = {The true meaning of 42},
    journal  = {Journal of modern skepticism},
    date     = {2016},
    keywords = {trusted},
}
@book{lion2010,
    author       = {Laura Lion and  Gabrielle Giraffe and Carl Capybara},
    title        = {The dangers of asking the wrong question},
    publisher    = {publishing house},
    date         = {2010},
    keywords     = {trusted},
}
@online{wikibook,
    title        = {Generating Bibliographies with biblatex and biber},
    organization = {Wikibooks},
    date         = {2016},
    urldate      = {2016-03-07},
    url          = {https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Generating_Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber},
    keywords     = {untrusted},
}
```

That I used to generate my citation using Biber in the following article

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lauraPhd2016.bib}
\begin{document}
I doubt that there is any useful information here~\cite{wikibook}.

All we know is limited, apart from knowing the answer we all know. Or do we? Wombat and Koala~\cite{wombat2016} have discovered some interesting things.

Some people are too nosy. What can happen to them is described by Laura Lion~\cite{lion2010}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the output I got is

[image: Output PDF file]

Now what I want to do is that instead of manually specifying `author \cite{key}`, I want to make `\cite` or `\something_other` directly do the entire job automatically. The output should be "Author/s name [numeric ref number]" as displayed in the output file. A simple method will be helpful for a beginner like me.

Comment: You are looking for `\textcite{ref}`.

Comment: Thank you very much, @pst, you saved my day :)

Comment: Just look up "3.8 Citation Commands" in the User Guide part of the documentation and you will find other commands you also may find useful.

Comment: can we include author year[numeric_ref] ? I was trying with  \usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,citestyle=authoryear,natbib=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}  but it was not printing [numeric_index]

Comment: If you want numeric citations, use only `style=numeric,` and not `citestyle=authoryear,`. With `citestyle=authoryear,` you get author-year citations and there `\textcite` produces `<author> (<year>)` and not `<author> [<number>]`.

Comment: @pst Do you want to type up a quick answer here? (I tried to find a good duplicate that explicitly mentions numeric styles, but didn't manage to find one with a quick search earlier, though I may just have had the wrong keywords.)

Comment: @moewe Nah, I'm on the run and don't really care.

Comment: @pst Fair enough, I added a quick answer to make sure the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [pst](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/48251/pst) [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559823/beginner-in-latex-how-to-cite-authornumeric-ref-in-citation?noredirect=1#comment1411935_559823), with numeric styles you can use `\textcite` to produce `<author> [<number>]` citations.

Generally, speaing `\textcite` produces textual/narrative citations where the author name(s) can be integrated in the text flow with an additional label part that makes the reference unique (the exact nature of the additional label depends on the citation style).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \textcite{sigfridsson}

ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem Sigfridsson and Ryde [1]//ipsum [1]]